# Create a number X of tables depending of a variable

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I' have a collection of fruits, the parameters that define a fruit is the kind of fruit and the weight.

I want to generate a table for each type of fruit in the data. For example; if in database exist apple, banana and mango, but in the data there only is apples and bananas it must generate just two tables, not three.

I' already know how to create tables and bind them to `DataSets`.

I don't know how to create a number X of tables. I could easily get the number of diferents fruits in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved it putting all the data in the same table.
After that i created a `row group` filtering by fruit type.
Finally i made invisible the headers of the table and i put a row over every `row group` another row that fakes to look like the headers.